# special mysql query from a joomla website

Tags: mysql, joomla

I have this context:

```
CREATE TABLE `atdees` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `params` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

INSERT INTO `atdees` (`id`, `params`) VALUES
(1,'{"field282":"0","field347":"1"}'),
(2,'{"field282":"0","field347":"0"}'),
(3,'{"field282":"0"}');
```

I have to extract from the table the rows where :

- an atdee must have the string '"field282":"0"'
- an atdee has the string '"field282":"0"' but not the string '"field347":"0"'
- an atdee has both string '"field282":"0"' and '"field347":"0"'

In other words I have to extract the Id 2 and 3.

Thank you.

Ps: Sorry for my english, I am not a native speaker ;)

edit: well i found my query

```
SELECT id
FROM atdees
WHERE
  INSTR(`params`, '"field282":"0"') > 0 and
  ( params LIKE '%"field347":"0"%' OR 
    INSTR(`params`, '"field347"') = 0 )
```

Comment: That is pretty much standard MySQL. Have you read up on the Joomla docs regarding database queries? -> http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply getting data from the database, then you can use something like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select($db->quoteName('id'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__atdees'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('params') . " = " . $db->quote('"field282":"0"') . "OR" . $db->quote('"field347":"0"'));

$db->setQuery($query);

$results = $db->loadObjectList();

foreach ( $results as $result ) {
    echo "<p>" . $result->id . "</p>";
}
```

Not sure if the database table is for a Joomla extensions but if so, keep it as `#__atdees` in your query, else change to `atdees`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your solution returns every rows.
I tried with LIKE, INSTR but to no avail.